# Changing git repo from public to private ruined jenkins connection

Tags: git, github, jenkins

All worked fine while my repo was public. Jenkins used credentials to connect to the repo through https. Now, once the repo type was switched to private, all the jobs are hanging on the line `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/username/SomeRepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` Is there any special labor need to be done to get this working? I tried to rename the URL to `git@github.com:username/SomeRepo.git` in the configuration page, didn't help. All positive responses will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to setup git credentials. Credentials can be login and password if your use https or ssh key if you use git.

You should setup and select it in build configuration.
Field next to scm url.

Comment: Well, I set them up (credentials) while was working with public repository. So not sure if need to set up completely new credentials for private repo. Basically it's the same username and password for GitHub account.

Comment: Can you check ${JENKINS_URL}/log/all
If there is any errors you will see the there.

Comment: Need to downgrade Jenkins to an older version probably as the url you provided is not reachable.